# DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR when passing glm::vec2 type using glUniformMatrix2fv

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I am trying to pass the frame size (X, Y) to my fragment shader. When I execute the GLAD function `glUniformMatrix2fv`, I get the following error:

> GL CALLBACK: ** GL ERROR ** type = "0x824c", severity = "0x9146", message = Error has been generated. GL error GL_INVALID_OPERATION

I use this method to pass `glm::vec4` datatypes (using `glUniformMatrix4fv`) for many other shaders without issue. I've looked up the error type, `0x824c`, and it appears to be a [DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/KHR/KHR_debug.txt). I have checked the function call in the [relevant documention](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glUniform.xml), and it appears to be correct. What am I missing?

Drawing code:

```
uFrameSizeID = glGetUniformLocation(shader->id(), "uFrameSize");
glUniformMatrix2fv(uFrameSizeID, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(
    glm::vec2(static_cast<float>(X_RESOLUTION), static_cast<float>(Y_RESOLUTION))));
```

Fragment Shader:

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

in VertexData
{
    vec4 color;
    vec2 texCoords;
} fs_in;

uniform sampler2D uTexture;
uniform sampler2D uDistortionMapX;
uniform sampler2D uDistortionMapY;
uniform vec4 uWindow;       // = [x0, y0, dx, dy]
uniform vec2 uFrameSize;    // = [X, Y] float

void main()
{
    vec2 v2_dist_vec;
    v2_dist_vec.x = texture(uDistortionMapX, fs_in.texCoords).r;
    v2_dist_vec.y = texture(uDistortionMapY, fs_in.texCoords).r;
    FragColor = texture(uTexture, fs_in.texCoords + v2_corr_vec);       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glUniformMatrix2fv` passes a **2x2** matrix. But in your shader you use `uniform vec2 uFrameSize;` which is a pair of floats. You must use `glUniform2fv`, or even simpler `glUniform2f`:

```
uFrameSizeID = glGetUniformLocation(shader->id(), "uFrameSize");
glUniform2f(uFrameSizeID, static_cast<float>(X_RESOLUTION), static_cast<float>(Y_RESOLUTION));
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks for finding my rookie mistake. I need more rep to upvote, but thank you.